# How do I flag questions about third-party APIs?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage

I am reviewing posts in the Triage queue and came across this one ([Call Of Duty API - How can I get a list of all user platforms by entering username only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65423835/call-of-duty-api-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-user-platforms-by-entering-userna)) which IMO basically boils down to the question "*How does the Call of Duty API work?*". As I understand it, this is [considered an unsuitable question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) on SO.

My question is: What action should I perform as a reviewer? Since [the primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort potentially problematic posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-review-queue-work), a I think a moderator flag is out of the question. Of the other options I'm left with I'd say flagging it as "This question has nothing to do with programming" is what comes closest for me, but that does not seem entirely accurate as well...

(Bear with me if this has been answered anywhere already, but I did not find anything and I have not been reviewing stuff for a long time yet...)

Comment: It's absolutely a programming question, just way too broad. Looks like it "needs author edit" to give it more focus, though I'm not sure what options you have in the queue with < 2k rep.

Comment: I'd vote to close (or flag) it as off-topic because it's looking for external resources (in this case, a tutorial for or even just the reference documentation of that API). That close reason is currently labelled "*Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Asking for help using an API is on-topic for Stack Overflow. If the question contains sufficient information to answer it, it should not be closed or flagged.

What [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) is trying to explain is that we don't answer *non-programming* questions about third-party APIs. For example, we don't answer questions about licensing, downtime, lost credentials, etc. We don't have access to the information needed to answer those types of questions.

> Since the primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort potentially problematic posts, a I think moderator flag is out of the question.

That is not true as a general rule. Flagging a post that is in need of moderator attention is a correct action in the Triage queue.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. This makes perfect sense and in the examples given in the FAQ, I guess flagging as "This question has nothing to do with programming" would not have prompted me to second guess my action.

Comment: If it truly has nothing to do with programming, please use that flag reason. If not, well... :-) Hopefully the reason is self-explanatory.